# Passsing null byte via format specifier in `printf`

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers, nul

Why does `printf` print a space instead of stopping when I use the NULL character from the ASCII table? This is what I mean:

```
printf("Hello%c, world", 0); //Hello , world
printf("Hello%c, world", '\0'); //Hello , world
```

Only when I put the escape character in the string itself `printf` stops the string:

```
printf("Hello\0, world"); //Hello
```

I tried this on Windows 8, Windows 10 (using cygwin, MinGW, Netbeans, Code::Blocks), XUbuntu, it's all the same.

Where is the problem? I asked one of my friends, but he said that he has no such problem, that all three examples executed the same way.

Comment: Why do you think the first 2 should print only Hello? [c++ example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d7e28cf27e49f71)

Comment: Because, 0 is the number of NULL/zero terminator in ASCII table, and its escaping character equivalent is '\0'.

Comment: @rozina, because `'\0'` is the null terminator character?

Comment: @AlterMann But OP told printf() to print a single character. What output do you expect for that? His implementation chose a white space. The c++ example I posted chose to ignore it. I don't know why it should terminate the input string, which obviously ends after the word "world".

Comment: @rozina Do you know how null-terminated strings work?

Comment: @cad Yes I do. The only null terminated string in the OP code I see is "Hello%c, world". Null comes after 'd'.

Comment: This question is equally applicable to both C++ and C, both have the same `printf` specification, so I think it should have both tags.

Comment: @rozina I put the both tags but I was suggested to chose only one language and I chose c.

Comment: That would be the better choice if you couldn't tag both, because no one uses `printf` in C++.

Comment: @rozina My question is principal. I am new in c and programming at all and I am trying to understand the logic and programming and C in particular. So don't wonder that I chose such meaningless example. The point is that according to my trainer all three examples must print the same output but they dont.

Comment: @zenith It is still used (embedded software for example).

Comment: You are taking a dependency on a printf() implementation detail.   The low-level terminal output function requires the length of the string as an argument.  So what matters is whether your printf() implementation calculates the length of the string *after* formatting or *while* formatting.  The latter is not uncommon.

Comment: @rozina, I know that, I'm just answering to your question: _Why do you think the first 2 should print only Hello?_

Comment: @rozina Yes of course. I meant virtually no one.

Comment: I guess that this question is related to why `printf("%");` is wrong, while OTOH, `printf("%s", "%");` is correct.

Comment: Show us your friend's **exact code** and we'll tell you where it is different from yours, or not.

Comment: First, there is no problem, this is expected behaviour. Second, what your friend sees depends on how his terminal handles `NUL`. I would be surprised, however, if he sees behaviour different from what you observe.

Answer (score 25):

`printf("Hello\0, world");` uses its parameter as a *C-string* so it decodes it until it finds a NUL char, so it stops just after `\0`, ignoring what follows.

`printf("Hello%c, world", 0);` decodes  its parameter (until it finds inside it a NUL char - i.e. after `d`), in the meanwhile it finds a `%c`, so it replaces it with the char given as parameter (whose ASCII code is NUL) and then send to the terminal a NUL char, and then continues.

Printf manual says:

> These functions write the output under the control of a format string 
>   that specifies how subsequent arguments [...] are converted for
>   output.

Comment: Got any reference to the Standard about this?

Comment: This is by definition of what a C-string is and printf format is for.

Comment: The question still remains - why in some compilators (as the one of my friend) the three examples execute the same.

Comment: Which compilers? Are you sure your friends really tested it?

Comment: Yes, I trust him. He uses net beans in Linux environment. I will investigate this matter deeper and will inform you if there was some musunderstanding in his part.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes, as I've said I have the same experience in Linux eighter but I'll check his compiler out just in case.

Comment: @sofia.bul  It is not completely surprising that `printf("Hello%c, world", 0);` on some system would incorrectly print "Hello , world" due to some faulty optimization.

Answer (score 6):

You are taking a dependency on a printf() implementation detail.  The low-level terminal output function requires the length of the string as an argument.  There are two ways for printf() to do this.

The somewhat obvious way is to *first* format the string, *then* use strlen().  That's the one you hoped for.

But that's inefficient because it requires a double pass across the string buffer and appending 0.  The other way to do it is track the formatted string length while substituting the fields, simply incrementing it for every appended character.  Since it continues past the %c, you'll now get the larger length that includes everything past %c.  What the terminal function does with the embedded 0 is an implementation detail as well, given that it is not a printable character.  Seeing it substituted with a space is not uncommon.

Sane way to go about this is to not rely on implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("Hello%c, world", 0); //Hello , world
printf("Hello%c, world", '\0'); //Hello , world
```

In both of these cases, you're trying to print out the character value corresponding to character code `0`, which is not a printable character.  I haven't found chapter and verse on it, but I suspect the behavior of trying to print a nul character value is unspecified or maybe even undefined.  Either way, I would not expect it to be treated as a string terminator in this case.

```
printf("Hello\0, world"); //Hello
```

In this case, the nul character is part of the string constant and is interpreted by the compiler as a string terminator.

Comment: NUL char is defined as a kind NOP for output.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès:  Chapter and verse?  I couldn't find any definitive language in the standard, but searching a pdf on an iPad is kind of a pain in the ass.

Comment: ASCII standard. **7.24** **NUL** (**NULL**). A control character used to accomplish media-fill or time-fill. NUL characters may be inserted into or removed from a stream of data without affecting the information content of that stream, but such action may affect the information layout and/or the control of equipment.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: What about non-ASCII implementations?  I was looking for language in the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) describing what should happen if you tried to print a null character using `%c`, and I can't find any.  This leads me to think that the behavior is undefined, and any result is possible.

Comment: @JohnBode The C standard only covers ... well, the C language. Printing a character has nothing to do with the language, and everything to do with the *device* on which this character will be printed (and that's what the ASCII standard covers). If we follow your logic, printing *any* character would be "undefined behaviour".

Comment: @MaëlNison: On the contrary, 5.2.2 describes character display semantics, including the intended behavior of non-graphical control characters (alert, form feed, line feed, etc.).  "The intent of writing a printing character (as defined by the `isprint` function) to a display device is to display a graphic representation of that character at the active position and then advance the active position to the next position on the current line."  The null character is not a printing character, and has no corresponding graphical representation.  I *think* the behavior is undefined, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

In short:
`%c` means to print a character, so `printf` print the `NUL` character which value is 0. `NUL` is a non-printing characters. So we can only see a space there.

"Hello\0, world" is a string literal, the result of `strlen("Hello\0, world")` is 5. So `printf` will print the result "Hello".

You can see more on website cppreference: [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

> A character string literal is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in double-quotes, as in "xyz". The null character ('\0') is always appended to the string literal, thus, a string literal "Hello" is a const char[6] holding the characters 'H', 'e','l','l','0', and '\0'. If a string literal has embedded null characters, it represents an array which contains more than one string.